# How to call a directive inside another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, compilation

this is my very first question in StackOverflow.

I'm working with AngularJS and I'm creating reusable boundingBox, Resizable and Draggable directives.

The idea of BoundingBox directive is that it should append the Draggable and Resizable directives to the *SAME* DOM element (if they didn't yet).

```
angular.module('WYSIRWYG.BoundingBox', [])
.directive('boundingBox', [function() {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    priority: -1000,

    compile: function($element, $attrs) {

        console.log($element.html());
        return {
            pre: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            },

            post: function($scope, $element) {
                $element
                .resizable({
                    handles: $attrs.bbHandles
                });
            }
        };
    }
};
}]);
```

and for the draggable directive:

```
angular.module('WYSIRWYG.Draggable', [])
.directive('draggable', [function() {

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: false,
    priority: -1000,

    compile: function($element, $attrs) {

        return {
            pre: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            },

            post: function($scope, $element) {
                $element
                .draggable({
                    delay: $attrs.dragDelay
                });
            }
        };
    }
};
}]);
```

and the DOM:

```
<div bounding-box bb-handles="n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw" style="background:red; width: 100px; height: 100px; display: block; position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 100px;">div content</div>
```

Notice that I didn't add Resizable nor Draggable attribute directives to the div so I hope that BoundingBox do it so.

The problem is I dont know how to make AngularJS to append this directives  to the current DOM element.
I've tried $compile but it gives infinite loop, since angular tries to compile BoundingBox again and again...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is indeed to use `$compile` in your `boundingBox` but only after you have removed the `bounding-box` attribute so it doesn't trigger a loop.

```
element.removeAttribute('bouding-box');
element.setAttribute('draggable');
$compile(element)(scope);
```